# Replacing categorical strings with ints in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a series containing data like

```
0 a
1 ab
2 b
3 a
```

And I want to replace any row containing 'b' to 1, and all others to 0. I've tried

```
one  = labels.str.contains('b')
zero = ~labels.str.contains('b')
labels.ix[one] = 1
labels.ix[zero] = 0
```

And this does the trick but it gives this pesky warning

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

And I know I've seen this before in the last few times I've used pandas. Could you please give the recommended approach? My method gives the desired result, but what should I do? Also, I think Python is supposed to be an 'if it makes logical sense and you type it it will run' kind of language, but my solution seems perfectly logical in the human-readable sense and it seems very non-pythonic that it throws an error.

Comment: I am not getting a warning. "labels" is probably a slice from a dataframe that you didn't include in the question. This part is just fine. All you do is assignment with boolean indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ds = pd.Series(['a','ab','b','a'])
ds
0     a
1    ab
2     b
3     a
dtype: object

ds.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'b' in x else 0)
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Output is `numpy.ndarray`, so you have to use `Series` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ser = pd.Series(['a','ab','b','a'])
print ser
0     a
1    ab
2     b
3     a
dtype: object

print np.where(ser.str.contains('b'),1,0)
[0 1 1 0]

print type(np.where(ser.str.contains('b'),1,0))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

print pd.Series(np.where(ser.str.contains('b'),1,0), index=ser.index)

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
dtype: int32
```